# Method that returns picture URL play framework

Tags: json, playframework

I have a a server where I upload pictures.I want to send the URL of the pictures with JSON to the android mobile phone in order to view them there.Is there a method which returns the URL of the resource?

Thanx in advance.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router.reverse("/public/images/someFile.png").absolute().url

should work.

Comment: The thing is that I've uploaded the pictures to the server and I don't really know where they are saved and thus I cannot give it to the JSON

Comment: when you upload the file like in 

public static void upload(File f)
{ 

}

you can move the file to a known location with a known name. You then create another method

public static void render(String someUniqueId){
 
   File f = new File(...); // lookup the file with the given id
    renderBinary(f);
}

Comment: Thank you for your help.:)One last thing.
Do you know how can I save a byte[] in MySql.I use @Lob but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry, I don't know. I'm using PostgreSQL.